# Zend Framework 2 detach Listeners in ListenerAggregateInterface

Tags: zend-framework2

I implemented a `ListenerAggregateInterface` for listening on the dispatch (`MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH`) event.

```
public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events) {
  $this->listeners[] = $events->attach(
    MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH,
    array($this, 'shortCircuit'),
    101
  );

  $this->listeners[] = $events->attach(
    MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH,
    array($this, 'listener1'),
    33
  );

  $this->listeners[] = $events->attach(
    MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH,
    array($this, 'listener2'),
    33
  );
}
```

If some condition in `shortCiruit` is `true` the rest of the listeners should be skipped. Therefore I call `ListenerAggregateInterface::detach` to remove all my listeners.

```
public function shortCircuit(MvcEvent $e) {
  if(condition) {
    $this->detach($e->getApplication()->getEventManager());
  }
}
```

I was expecting that they are now not executed anymore, but this is not the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Detaching listeners for the currently triggered event won't work while listeners are being dispatched. That is because [the listeners are collected and sorted before they are actually executed](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/7688fab93de0b94c3469c798cbb2d36d301bfce3/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php#L443-L449) in order to sort them by their priority.

Stopping propagation would also not work with your current approach, since you want to disable only a particular set of listeners.

There is a solution though, which is to skip your listeners only when needed, using a small registry to record events to be skipped by your aggregate listener. I wrote this off the top of my head, so it's un-tested, please unit test it carefully if you want use it:

```php
use SplObjectStorage;
use Zend\EventManager\EventInterface;

final class SkippedEventsRegistry {
    /** @var SplObjectStorage */
    private $skippedEvents;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->skippedEvents = new SplObjectStorage();
    }

    /**
     * @param callable $callback
     * @return callable
     */
    public function buildCallback(callable $callback)
    {
        return function ($event) use ($callback) {
            if (isset($this->skippedEvents[$event])) {
                return;
            }

            return $callback($event);
        };
    }

    public function skipListenersForEvent(EventInterface $event) {
        $this->skippedEvents[$event] = $event;
    }

    public function restoreListenersForEvent(EventInterface $event) {
        unset($this->skippedEvents[$event]);
    }
}
```

Then we use this registry within our aggregate listener:

```php
use Zend\EventManager\EventInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\ListenerAggregateInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\ListenerAggregateTrait;

class MyAggregateListener implements ListenerAggregateInterface {
    use ListenerAggregateTrait;
    private $skippedEvents;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->skippedEvents = new SkippedEventsRegistry();
    }

    public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events) {
        $this->listeners[] = $events->attach('SomeEvent',
            $this->skippedEvents->buildCallback(function ($event) {
            // ... do other things here ...
            if ($worldIsExploding) {
                    // start skipping the other listeners
                    $this->skippedEvents->skipListenersForEvent($event);
                }
            }), 9999);

        $this->listeners[] = $events->attach('SomeEvent',
            $this->skippedEvents->buildCallback(function ($event) {
                // ... do other things here ...
            }), 8888);

        // reset normal execution 
        // (sadly, happens only if propagation wasn't stopped)
        $this->listeners[] = $events->attach(
            'SomeEvent',
            [$this->skippedEvents, 'restoreListenersForEvent'],
            -9999999999
        );
    }
}
```

(Sorry for the alignment mess-up, but it's quite hard to fit everything within the overflow :\ )

As you can see, we are simply stopping listeners from being executed when the event was marked as "skipped" through the registry. That happens when the `$worldIsExploding = true` during the first listener execution.

After that, we execute all other listeners and clean up at the end through a low-priority listener.

Eventually, you can also call `$this->skippedEvents->restoreListenersForEvent($event)` in an event listener with a high priority. That prevents listeners from being skipped even if the same `$event` instance is used with multiple `Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface#trigger()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to roll-your-own short circuiting as [the event manager already provides this functionality](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.event-manager.event-manager.html#zend-event-manager-event-manager-examples-short-circuiting) . All you will need to do is use `$event->stopPropagation(true);` within an event listener.

For example

```
public function shortCircuit(MvcEvent $e) {
    if(condition) {
        $e->stopPropagation(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `$e->stopPropagation(true)` stops everything and I receive a blank page with only the layout, but nothing else filled. Which says that the whole process after `dispatch` was canceled. I just want my listeners in this aggregate to to stop executing, not all that comes after.

Comment: Maybe cancel is the wrong choice of words, I want to skip the rest of the listeners that I added in this aggregate.

Comment: old topic, but maybe you could trigger another event in the event listener (pass along the mvcevent variable), add your listeners to this new event and you would be able to short circuit without affecting the dispatch listeners.